# Show popup from Chrome Extension - like Evernote Web Clipper

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications, evernote

I'm writing my first chrome extension. I want to show a popup message in order to confirm user's action. From the chrome extension documentation, I understand how to specify popup.html in manifest.json file here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

But this only talks about showing popup.html when user clicks the extension Icon in the browser.

I would like to know how I can show this popup.html from background.js script in my chrome extension. (instead of user having to click the extension Icon, I want to show this popup when user selects a context menu option that my chrome extension has added)

Example: If you have a chrome extension for everynote web clipper, when you clip something and save to your evernote account it shows a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Popups can only be displayed when a user clicks on the browserAction. There is no way for you to open it from code. Instead you should use [notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/richNotifications).

Example

```
var notificationId;
var options = {
  type: "basic",
  title: "Primary Title",
  message: "Primary message to display",
  iconUrl: "url_to_small_icon"
}
var callback = function(wasUpdated) {};

chrome.notifications.create(notificationId, options, callback);
```

Comment: these notifications are shown in system tray and not in browser, where as evernote web clipper shows notifications in browser

Comment: Notifications are the preferred way of telling users something happened. If you want something more advanced you either need to trigger it by a user clicking on the browserAction button or inject HTML directly in the current page.